# A protocol message was rejected because it was too big (more than 67108864 bytes) on mesos

Tags: apache-spark, k-means, mesos

Kmeans  on spark  by mesos
16/10/15 19:10:41 WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 54 contains a task of very large size (212070 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.

```
[Stage 54:>   
                                                  (0 + 1) / 10]``
[Stage 54:>                                                        (0 + 2) / 10]
[Stage 54:>                                                        (0 + 3) / 10]
[Stage 54:>                                                        (0 + 4) / 10]
[Stage 54:>                                                        (0 + 5) / 10]
[Stage 54:>                                                        (0 + 6) / 10]
[Stage 54:>                                                        (0 + 7) / 10]
[Stage 54:>                                                        (0 + 8) / 10]
[Stage 54:>                                                        (0 + 9) / 10]
[Stage 54:>                                                       (0 + 10) / 10][libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.cc:180] A protocol message was rejected because it was too big (more than 67108864 bytes).  To increase the limit (or to disable these warnings), see CodedInputStream::SetTotalBytesLimit() in google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h.
F1015 19:10:48.392988 25634 construct.cpp:46] Check failed: parsed Unexpected failure while parsing protobuf
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7fa3dab98d18  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @     0x7fa3dab98c67  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x7fa3dab98678  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x7fa3dab9b3ac  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @     0x7fa3dab7f68b  parse<>()
    @     0x7fa3dab7e274  construct<>()
    @     0x7fa3dab865d4  Java_org_apache_mesos_MesosSchedulerDriver_launchTasks__Ljava_util_Collection_2Ljava_util_Collection_2Lorg_apache_mesos_Protos_00024Filters_2
    @     0x7fa4d90127f8  (unknown)
```